# Shift back tense in reported speech

Tags: past-tense, questions, present-tense, perfect-aspect

I have a situation as below:

> A: Who read my diary?
> B: I didn't read it
> A: It is only you who read it.
> B: I told you I didn't read it/ I told you I hadn't had read it.

Is that both sentences are correct for this situation ?
Grammar books write that the standard way is to back shift, but sometimes we don't need to back shift
But I don't know if we need to back shift for this situation or not, if not, why?

Comment: It is fairly common to backshift when the reporting follows some time after the saying - but I would not call this "standard" in spoken language. However, in this case the reporting follows immediately after the saying, and the backshift to the past perfect seems very unnatural.

Comment: We don't say "hadn't had read it". Presumably you mean "hadn't read it".

Comment: Dear  Peter Shor,
Yes, It was my mistake, It must be "hadn't read it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to backshift reported speech, but it is not a required grammar rule.  When you are reporting speech you are telling a story.  If you are telling that story as a past tense narrative then when you report someone speaking in the past tense, the events that they speak about must have happened before the time of the narrative, and so it is natural to use past perfect.

But in this situation, B isn't telling a story to A about the things he said. B is just repeating himself. There is no narrative and no need to backshift.

If, later that day B is talking to C:

> B: I 'm upset with 'A'. He accused me of reading his diary.  I told him that I hadn't read it, but he still kept accusing me.

Here there is a story, and it would be natural for B to backshift the reported speech.  (I'm assuming A and B use he/him pronouns, it makes no difference)

Note "told him I hadn't read it", not "hadn't had read it"  And "It is only you who read it." is unnatural perhaps "You're the only person who could've read it!"

Comment: Dear James K
Thanks so much for your explanation. 
It is so useful to me

Comment: Dear James K, Noted your message, already up-voted and accepted the answer